# Error after updating .NET Framework 4.6.1 to 4.8

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ninject, .net-4.8

I updated my application from .NET Framework 4.6.1 to 4.8 but I have an error loading the application.

For context: This application uses the Ninject Nuget for dependency injection. This nuget automatically creates a file called "NinjectWebCommon.cs" inside the App_Start folder
In this ninject file I am having an error with the StandardKernel(); method

```
 private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
```

The error I am having is this:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Cannot load file or assembly
> 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified.'

Searching for a solution I found that I needed to have inside the Web.config a binding redirect, but I already have it.

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I also have on the project references System.Net.Http, so I don't know what could it be

Comment: One of your dependencies has a dependency upon System.Web.Http version 4.2

Comment: Also, be aware that System.Net.Http is completely different to System.Web.Http.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the dependentAssembly for System.Net.Http and it worked. I don't know if that is the optimal solution btw

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  This is what I did to resolve it, AFTER upgrading to 4.8.

1. Removed NuGet Package System.Net.Http
2. Re-Added the Reference System.Net.Http
3. In App.config removed the bindingredirect line for system.net.http

Worked like a charm!